# store arrays result from a for loop in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Mainly I have this dictionary rhs

```
rhs
{{('1', '3'): [0.06081006262521797, 0.4965853037914095], ('1', '4'): [0.0018363047770289071], ('3', '2'): [0.4965853037914095]}
type(rhs1)
<class 'dict'>
```

I tried to normalize only the values in rhs and store them again in another dictionary `rhs_normalized` so the sum of values for each key must equals 1 but I couldn't! I need to store them in this way to be able later to call each array of values belongs to a certain key like:

```
 rhs_normalized
{('1', '3'): [0.10909682119561295, 0.8909031788043871], ('1', '4'): [1.0], ('3', '2'): [1.0]}
```

so I wrote

```
rhs
{{('1', '3'): [0.06081006262521797, 0.4965853037914095], ('1', '4'): [0.0018363047770289071], ('3', '2'): [0.4965853037914095]}
type(rhs1)
<class 'dict'>

rhs_normalized = {}
for each_array in list(rhs1.values()):
  each_array_of_values_equal = []
  for i in each_array :
    each_array_of_values_equal.append(i/sum(each_array))
    rhs_normalized[each_array] = each_array_of_values_equal
```

I got this error

```
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I think the error because of `rhs_normalized[each_array]` since, as I understood, I tried to use a list as a key for a dictionary and this key is not hashable!

It seems a common error for beginners so I tried many solutions available on the internet but without success. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your lists as dict keys (which are unhashable and can't be used as keys). Per your example output, I think you mean to use the existing dict keys and transform the list values.

For example (simplified the process of building your second dict a bit):

```
data = {('1', '3'): [0.06081006262521797, 0.4965853037914095], ('1', '4'): [0.0018363047770289071], ('3', '2'): [0.4965853037914095]}

result = {k: [v / sum(vals) for v in vals] for k, vals in data.items()}
print(result)
# {('1', '3'): [0.10909682119561295, 0.8909031788043871], ('1', '4'): [1.0], ('3', '2'): [1.0]}
```